# How to get a list of all config args?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

How can get a list of all config args?

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
root.config(**args)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried with:

```
help(root.config)
```

The output:

> Help on method configure in module tkinter:
>
> configure(cnf=None, **kw) method of tkinter.Tk instance
>   Configure resources of a widget.
>
> The values for resources are specified as keyword
>   arguments. To get an overview about
>   the allowed keyword arguments call the method keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "config args"? Do you mean all configurable options for a certain widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "config args" you mean all the configurable attributes of a particular widget, you can obtain them like this:

```
my_widget.config()
```

In other words, what you just need to do is calling the method `config` (or `configure`, which is simply an alias) without arguments, which returns a _dictionary with the attributes, their values and more of the widget.

You could also use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter.pprint) function (from the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pprint.html) module) to print nicely the attributes, like in the following example:

```
from tkinter import *
from pprint import pprint

root = Tk()
pprint(root.config())
```

And the output is the following:

```
{'background': ('background',
                'background',
                'Background',
                <border object: 'systemWindowBody'>,
                'systemWindowBody'),
 'bd': ('bd', '-borderwidth'),
 'bg': ('bg', '-background'),
 'borderwidth': ('borderwidth',
                 'borderWidth',
                 'BorderWidth',
                 <pixel object: '0'>,
                 0),
 'class': ('class', 'class', 'Class', 'Toplevel', 'Tk'),
 'colormap': ('colormap', 'colormap', 'Colormap', '', ''),
 'container': ('container', 'container', 'Container', 0, 0),
 'cursor': ('cursor', 'cursor', 'Cursor', '', ''),
 'height': ('height', 'height', 'Height', <pixel object: '0'>, 0),
 'highlightbackground': ('highlightbackground',
                         'highlightBackground',
                         'HighlightBackground',
                         <color object: 'systemWindowBody'>,
                         'systemWindowBody'),
 'highlightcolor': ('highlightcolor',
                    'highlightColor',
                    'HighlightColor',
                    <color object: 'Black'>,
                    'Black'),
 'highlightthickness': ('highlightthickness',
                        'highlightThickness',
                        'HighlightThickness',
                        <pixel object: '0'>,
                        0),
 'menu': ('menu', 'menu', 'Menu', '', ''),
 'padx': ('padx', 'padX', 'Pad', <pixel object: '0'>, <pixel object: '0'>),
 'pady': ('pady', 'padY', 'Pad', <pixel object: '0'>, <pixel object: '0'>),
 'relief': ('relief', 'relief', 'Relief', <index object: 'flat'>, 'flat'),
 'screen': ('screen', 'screen', 'Screen', '', ''),
 'takefocus': ('takefocus', 'takeFocus', 'TakeFocus', '0', '0'),
 'use': ('use', 'use', 'Use', '', ''),
 'visual': ('visual', 'visual', 'Visual', '', ''),
 'width': ('width', 'width', 'Width', <pixel object: '0'>, 0)}
```

According to the documentation regarding the `config` method at [effbot.org](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method):

> **`config(cnf=None, **kw)`**
>
> Modifies one or more widget options.
>
> If called without an argument, this method returns a dictionary containing the current settings for all widget options. **For each *option key* in the dictionary, the value is either a *five-tuple* `(option, option database key, option database class, default value, current value)`, or a *two-tuple* `(option alias, option)`. The latter case is used for aliases like `bg` (`background`) and `bd` (`border width`)**.
>
> Note that the value fields aren’t correctly formatted for some option types. See the description of the keys method for more information, and a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Axl for your answer .

```
from tkinter import *

from pprint import pprint

root=Tk()

pprint(root.key())
```

this code also works for me .